# What are private methods for in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Am I missing out something?

```
class Circus
  private
  def start
    puts 'And now for something completely different..'
  end
end
```

And for my disillusion:

```
c=Circus.new
c.start               #NoMethodError: private method `start' called
c.method(:start).call #no problem at all
c.send :start        #neither this fails
```

Can anybody give me a reason why private methods exist in Ruby?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put it this way. In Ruby you could just as easily monkey-patch a public method into a class which invoked the private method, so... Why *would* `private` prevent your behaviour?

You seem to think that `private` methods are somehow a *security* thing, that they *have* to be inaccessible outside the class. Encapsulation isn't about security, is a tool for producing clean, maintainable code. It's up to you to respect the interface exposed by a class. If you *really* want to find a way to invoke a private method, you will. Ruby cannot *enforce* this completely, nor should it have to; it would be counter-productive and a waste of time.

> I mean, can anybody give me at least one reason why 'private' even exists in Ruby?

For the exact same reason `private` exists in *any other OOP-based language*: [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)). Really, you think that just because you can find a convoluted way to circumvent `private`, it should just be thrown out?

Answer (score 6):

It declares the intent of the method.  If it's private you're not supposed to call it and you should be aware that doing so may cause unpredictable or undesirable behaviour.

For what it's worth, this behaviour is not limited to Ruby - it is possible to access private members and variables in Java as well, via the Reflection API.

Answer (score 0):

Private methods are *supposed to be* called only from inside the same instance, without explicit receiver. They will fail whenever explicit receiver is supplied, including `self.some_private_method` called from the same instance. The ability to bypass this via `send` is a nonstandard coding practice, that should be used mainly for maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start using reflection, all bets are off. That's not unique to Ruby, by the way, almost every language that has reflection has this problem.

You can mitigate this by using coding standards and code reviews, e.g. always use `public_send` etc. But if you don't like this, you will need to use a language with a properly stratified reflection system such as Newspeak.